# command hangs head / netcat

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, head, netcat

I am using two linux machines to simulate some firewall tests... I execute the tests by running `nc` through ssh on a remote machine... if I spawn the `ssh` like this, it works...

```
ssh -i id_dsa -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
    -p 2224 root@a2-idf-lab nc -s 10.26.216.82 10.195.18.132 \
    21 < /var/log/messages
```

However, if I try to control how much of `/var/log/messages` with `head -c 20 /var/log/messages`, the command hangs but I don't understand why...

```
ssh -i id_dsa -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
    -p 2224 root@a2-idf-lab nc -s 10.26.216.82 10.195.18.132 \
    21 < head -c 20 /var/log/messages
```

I also tried this with no better success...

```
ssh -i id_dsa -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
    -p 2224 root@a2-idf-lab nc -s 10.26.216.82 10.195.18.132 \
    21 < (head -c 20 /var/log/messages)
```

Question: Why does the second command hang, and how can I accomplish what I need?

FYI, these experiments were really in preparation for sending `cat /dev/urandom | base64 | head -c 20 -` into `nc`... bonus points if you can give me cli that would work with `nc` through an ssh session...

Comment: Try `head -c 20 /var/log/messages | ssh ...` or ``ssh ... `head -c 20 /var/log/messages` ``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<` is shell redirection, it redirects the input stream to read from a file, not to execute a command. try:

```
head -c 20 /var/log/messages | ssh -i id_dsa -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null \
  -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
  -p 2224 root@a2-idf-lab nc -s 10.26.216.82 10.195.18.132 21
```

this pipes `/var/log/messages` from the local machine into `nc` on the remote machine.
if you want to use the `/var/log/messages` file on the remote machine, use quotes around the command:

```
ssh -i id_dsa -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
  -p 2224 root@a2-idf-lab "head -c 20 /var/log/messages |\
     nc -s 10.26.216.82 10.195.18.132 21"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use
    head -n 20
My guess is the problem is the lack of carriage return  at the end.